# What height is atmospheric pressure half that at sea level?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, atmospheric-science, ideal-gas, fluid-statics

[image: Atmospheric Pressure Half that at Sea Level]
$PV = NT$, where T is a constant

$P = \rho g h$ but I don't think this equation can hold in this form as the density is most definitely not constant as we go up in the atmosphere

$\rho = \frac{M}{V}$

We can change it such that $\rho(h) = \frac{M}{V(h)}$, $P(h) = \rho(h) g h$

But I don't know how to suitably find the equation for $\rho$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is along the right lines and you need to make use that $dp = \rho(z) \, g \, dz$ and use the relationship between pressure, volume and temperature for n moles of gas as $P V = n R T$, so that $P = \frac{n}{V} R T = \rho R T$, with $\rho$ the density.

If you assume that the temperature of the atmosphere is uniform then the pressure varies as height like $P(z) = P_0 \, exp(-\frac{M g z}{R T})$, with $M$ the molar mass of air, $g$ the acceleration due to gravity (assumed constant), $R$ the gas constant and $T$ the (absolute) temperature. The factor $\frac{R T}{Mg}$ has the units of length and determines a scale factor. For STP have $\frac{R T}{Mg} \approx \, 10 \, km$. However, there are other models that drop the assumption of constant temperature, have a look at (for example)https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula. As well, the following link may be of use: [Is it possible to calculate atmospheric pressure if given temperature (F) and elevation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54429/is-it-possible-to-calculate-atmospheric-pressure-if-given-temperature-f-and-el?rq=1).

Comment: I realise the problem I had. I was confused as I thought $dP = \rho(z) g dz + g z d\rho(z)$, but for $d \rho(z)$, the z is constant, meaning $d \rho(z) = 0$. Thank makes much more sense. Many thanks.

Comment: Please do not post complete solutions to homework-like problems.

Comment: The student was along the right track and just needed to put in the result for $P vs \rho$. The solution assuming $T =$ constant involving the exponential equation is not difficult, as well it was given in terms of the molar mass and so requires some manipulation by the student. The scale distance of $10 km$ is only approximate and would require the student to put in the relevant numbers and can be used for checking.